# Echo specific term in an array

Tags: custom-taxonomy, array

I have a custom hierarchical taxonomy ('location') that looks like:

```
Tokyo
--Minato
----Roppongi
```

I have a post where only "Roppongi" is selected and I want to display as text only the top level parent term of the taxonomy (Tokyo) without any category link.

```
<?php $myterms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'location', 'parent' => 0 ) );?>
```

The above code gives me...

> Array ( [0] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 11 [name] => Tokyo [slug]
>   => tokyo [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 11 [taxonomy] => location [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 0 [filter] => raw )
>   )

... as an output if I use...

```
<?php print_r($myterms);?>
```

... to display the result at the front-end. How do I display only the [name] value in the array? I tried the below code but get an error.

```
<?php echo $myterms[0]['name'];?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is an object, and you can use the following notation:

```
<?php echo $myterms[0]->name; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! This works for my example, but I other prefectures listed in my taxonomy and so it's shows 'Aichi' not Tokyo... how do I specify that it has to be the [name] from that term ID?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. You will need post ID and the taxonomy name:

```
function wpse_290965_top_level_tax_name( $post_id, $tax )
{
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $tax );

    $anc = get_ancestors( $terms[0]->term_id, $tax );
    $parent = array_values( array_slice( $anc, -1 ) )[0];

    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $parent, $tax );
    return $term->name;
}
```

Now call it like: `<?php echo wpse_290965_top_level_tax_name( 234, 'location' ); ?>`

Here 234 is an example of post ID.